# Cookie not being set in IE using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm having trouble setting a cookie in IE 9/10/11 it works fine in Chrome/Firefox/Safari. I have tried things suggested in other questions on StackOverflow to no avail and have obviously checked the IE security settings.

The cookie is being set with a simple function

```
function setCookie(name,value,expiredays) {
    if (expiredays > 0) {
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
        expires="; expires="+exdate.toUTCString();
    } else {
        expires="; expires=0";
    }

    document.cookie=name+"="+value+expires;
}
```

and being called in one of two places (neither work)

```
jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
    callbacks: {
        close: function() {
            setCookie('seenSummer','summer',0);
        }
    },
    alignTop: true,
    items: [
        {
            src: '#summer-popup',
            type: 'inline'
        }
    ]
});

jQuery('.popup__btn').on('click', function() {
    setCookie('seenSummer','summer',0);
});
```

Comment: a couple of questions: do you have cookies enabled in IE? Is your security level set to high? Are you trying this on localhost? Do you have underscore in your domain name?

Comment: Did you try setting cookies without '; expires=0' when 0 is set as expiry days ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure exactly what the problem was, but using this library sorted the problem out.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support